# linking OpenCV2.3 to the enthought's python2.7

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-10.04, enthought

I have just installed the enthought package on an Ubuntu 10.4 machine under:

```
/home/epd
```

the python package is under

```
/home/epd/lib/python2.7
```

I also installed opencv under

```
/home/Opencv
```

However I could not manage to link both. I tried with :

1- create a .pth file with the content address of opencv added to the site-packages of python2.7, but it did not work.

2- tried with

```
ln -s /home/Opencv
```

and did not work

Any further suggestions

Comment: By default the OpenCV build system will choose the most recent version of Python that it can find, or you can force it to use a specific version using the PYTHON_EXECUTABLE variable when you invoke cmake http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

Comment: I have tried to set the PYTHON_EXECUTABLE to the new location of python2.7  but I did not work for me, could you specify where to change exactly ?

Comment: >> PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=path cmake ...

Comment: The solution of adding setting some variables as you stated does not work on linux, I think this is becuase in linux cv.so is being installed into dist-packages, all what I had to do is to get the cv.so from a my own linux machine and put it in site-packages, How silly!! but it worked.